# How to do I send a timestamped image to MySQL with an edit multiple image form?

Tags: php, mysql

How do i get a unique image to MySQL and still be able to edit just one image at a time? I only have the ability to update 4 images at once with a unique id or I can edit the images seperatly and have them update without a unique id.

```
    <?php

require_once('storescripts/connect.php');
mysql_select_db($database_phpimage,$phpimage);
$uploadDir = 'upload/';
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{


foreach ($_FILES as $file)
{

    $fileName = $file['name'];
    $tmpName = $file['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $file['size'];
    $fileType = $file['type'];

    if ($fileName != ""){
        $filePath = $uploadDir;
        $fileName = str_replace(" ", "_", $fileName);

        //Split the name into the base name and extension
        $pathInfo = pathinfo($fileName);
        $fileName_base = $pathInfo['fileName'];
        $fileName_ext = $pathInfo['extension'];

        //now we re-assemble the file name, sticking the output of uniqid into it
        //and keep doing this in a loop until we generate a name that 
        //does not already exist (most likely we will get that first try)
        do {
           $fileName = $fileName_base . uniqid() . '.' . $fileName_ext;
        } while (file_exists($filePath.$fileName));

        $file_names [] = $fileName;

        $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath.$fileName);
    }


if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$fileName = addslashes($fileName);
$filePath = addslashes($filePath);
}
$fileinsert[] = $filePath;
}
}

$mid   = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['mid']));
$cat   = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['cat']));
$item  = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['item']));
$price = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['price']));
$about = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['about']));

$fields = array();
$values = array();
$updateVals = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
    $values[$i] = isset($file_names[$i]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($file_names[$i]) : '';

    if($values[$i] != '')
    {
        $updateVals[] = "{$fields[$i]} = '{$values[$i]}'";
    }

}
$updateNames = '';
if(count($updateVals))
{
    $updateNames = ", " . implode(', ', $updateVals);
}

$update = "INSERT INTO image
               (mid, cid, item, price, about, name1, name2, name3, name4)
           VALUES
               ('$mid', '$cat', '$item', '$price', '$about', '$values[0]', '$values[1]', '$values[2]', '$values[3]')
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                cid = '$cat', item = '$item', price = '$price', about = '$about' $updateNames";
$result = mysql_query($update) or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your `foreach ($_FILES as $file) {` loop you are renaming and saving the uploaded file but you are using the original filenames when inserting into the db. You need to store the renamed files in the db. After your `do ... while` loop assign the new filename to an array -

```
do {
    $fileName = $fileName_base . uniqid() . '.' . $fileName_ext;
} while (file_exists($filePath.$fileName));
$file_names[] = $fileName;
```

then modify your for loop to -

```
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
    $values[$i] = isset($filenames[$i]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($filenames[$i]) : '';

    if($values[$i] != '') {
        $updateVals[] = 'name' . ($i + 1) . " = '{$values[$i]}'"; 
    }
}
```

and finally, update your update statement to -

```
$update = "INSERT INTO image
               (mid, cid, item, price, about, name1, name2, name3, name4)
           VALUES
               ('$mid', '$cat', '$item', '$price', '$about', '$values[0]', '$values[1]', '$values[2]', '$values[3]')
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                cid = '$cat', item = '$item', price = '$price', about = '$about' $updateNames";
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '4f640e00097bc.jpg'' at line 6

Comment: where is there an extra "equal sign" being passed to the value?

Comment: Try `die($update);` instead of actually executing the query and post the output.

Comment: INSERT INTO image (mid, cid, item, price, about, name1, name2, name3, name4) VALUES ('167', 'hats', 'zzz', 'zz', 'zz', '4f64105aad275.jpg', '', '', '') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cid = 'hats', item = 'zzz', price = 'zz', about = 'zz' , = '4f64105aad275.jpg'

Comment: Ok. The error is obvious and it shows a floor in your update logic. The way you have it currently will update all four image names on update, which is bad. If you update without any images there will not be any images saved against the item. This is a typical example of why such a denormalised structure is bad. Please modify your original question so that reflects the code as you have it now.

Comment: That is what I meant by your update logic being floored. Why do you have a single record in your image table for a record that can contain four images?

Comment: because its an array that broke down into 4 images if i chose to edit 4. but usually I would only edit one at a time. it works fine i just can't get that timestamp to mysql on this edit form. i am brand new to php and thats the only way i could think of how to edit multiple images.

Comment: That was not what I meant. One image record should represent one image, not four images. There is no reference to a timestamp in your current question. Do you mean the call to uniqid()? You can remove the error reference at the top of your question now.

Comment: How would I pass the values of the other 3 images then without uploading the files manually?

Comment: Unfortunately, because your reputation is low (new member) we cannot move this discussion to chat. Do you have any other form of messaging available?

Comment: i can get whatever though IRC?